# How to retain completed applications after yarn server restart in spark web-ui

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am using yarn resource manager for spark. after restart of yarn server, all completed jobs in spark-webui disappered.

Below two properties added in yarn-site.xml Can someone explain me what could be the reason and is there any property to control this.

```
<property>
      <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
      <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds</name>
    <value>86400</value>
</property>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can persist application history on restarts if you set `yarn.resourcemanager.recovery.enabled` to `true` in your yarn-site.xml and set `yarn.resourcemanager.store.class`.

See [ResourceManger Restart](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRestart.html) for further details.

Your other entries refer to logging and define how long you want completed logs to stay before they get cleaned out.  You can read more about them in [yarn-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml).

Comment: Thank you !. with above two properties, I am able to see the completed applications in yarn-webui after yarn restart. But when I clicc on the logs, getting "java.lang.Exception: Unknown container. Container either has not started or has already completed or doesn't belong to this node at all" .  Can you please help me to get those logs as well after restart!.  Much appreciated for your help!.

Comment: It's impossible to tell why you're seeing that error based on your original question.  But you could post a new question and include all relevant details like your config XML files and see if someone knows why you're seeing that.